# Stuck at creating project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

[image: photo link]

I am stuck at this screen. I have already waited for very long time, but it still don't have any response. I also have searched so many solutions and i have tried them all. This situation still happens.

Comment: are you sure you have the permission in the folder where you are trying to create this project, try opening `Visual Studio` with `Run as administrator`

Comment: still the same.

Comment: Even with administrator access, have you tried just for test to change the location for project folder and name as well just a guess

Comment: If it's possible try reinstalling the software might

Comment: thanks, but i tried them all before....

Comment: i just find out another related problem: when i click the toolbox and move my mouse to the toolbox window, the vs2017 stop working immediately. maybe these two problem are related?

Comment: omg, this is very bad

Comment: maybe i forgot to install some important and related applications?

Comment: Yeah maybe try to repair it

Comment: tried already...

Comment: i should install another development tool instead of visual studio 2017 !!!

Comment: Have you tried asking foir help from  microsoft itself they might be able to help, if still not then I suppose try some other development tool

Comment: i tried that already, today i try to use vs2013 but the project still occur

Comment: that microsoft guy remote my computer for a few hours, then he said sorry and told me that i should find another higher level support staff. i go to that web and find, and then i discovered that it needs money....

Comment: This question is still relevant for Visual Studio 2022.  The one answer worked, at least for me (the option to launch as admin); it should be accepted

Answer (score 3):

I had that problem but now fixed. Try following

- Delete Visual Studio Settings Folder From Documents Menu.
- Start Visual Studio In Administrator Mode.
- First Open Existing Project, And Then Try To Create New Project.

OR
- Create new user  (with full rights of administrator). Use it.

[image]

Comment: For some reason I didn't have this catalog in 'Visual Studio 2017' folder. But I had it in 'Visual Studio 2015'  and after removing 'settings' I was able to create new projects in vs 2017. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue in VS 2022 - but had no `settings` sub folder here. I just deleted the entire `Visual Studio 2022` folder from my documents and then rebooted VS. That seemed to sort it out and it repopulated the folder on its own.